# Recommendation for model output test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, model

I have shell length data for mussels at 6 different sites (AS, GSF, LM, EM, ES1, LS1). At each site, I ran a model to predict their growth for present day and the next 5 decades, i.e., growth at 2017, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, and 2060. The model runs for 730 days. I am using SPSS and it looks something like this:

```
Time(Days)    Length    Site    Year
 1            2.78      AS      2017
 2            2.789     AS      2017
 3            2.79      AS      2017
```

So, in total with all sites, I have 26,279 observations in SPSS.

My question is stated above: What tests would you recommend I run in SPSS that would statistically prove a difference per year? I used the split file function in SPSS to compare the groups by site already. Any help from you guys would be most appreciated! How could I use a 'multi-lateral' t-test to compare all the groups?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a model that is predicting this, then I don't see what you are testing: You know what the model predicts.  You don't have observations, you have predictions.  You don't have a sample from a population.

If you had data from the past, then you could ask about an appropriate model (I'd suggest a multilevel model) and there would be associated significance.  But here, that doesn't make sense.